# access jenkins build artifacts in postbuild-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to access the previously build artifacts in a post-build-plugin? If yes, how do I access them?

For example:
My build creates a .jar file as an artifact.
In my plugin, I would like to access that .jar file and send it to an external server. That server is going to evaluate the file and depending on the result, I'd like to mark the build as failed/unstable/successful.

Answer (score 0):

All build artifacts are in the workspace, in the same path the previous step saved them, ie `build/libs/foo.jar`. If you click in workspace, you can find it there, and it would be available for any post-build-plugin if you dont move it or delete it. Post build steps are executed in the workspace so it should be accessible with ie `./build/libs/foo.jar`